# Is There A Way To Change The Keyboard Type In DialogInput In React Native?

Tags: react-native, components

I have been trying to change the keyboard type of my DialogInput component in React Native using the "KeyboardType" prop however it is not working. Am I doing it incorrectly or is this prop not supported by DialogInputs?
Here is my Code Snippet

```
const userDialogInput = (props) => {
return ( 
    <DialogInput 
        keyboardType= "numeric"
        isDialogVisible={props.visible}
        title={props.title}
        message={props.messsage}
        submitInput={ (inputText) => props.saveInput(inputText, props.title)}
        closeDialog={() => props.closeDialog()}
    />
 );}
```

Thank you

Comment: Is this component the same as https://github.com/joseestrella89/react-native-dialog-input?

Comment: yes it is .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs, you need to specify the keyboardType inside another prop. Just like:

```
const userDialogInput = (props) => {
return ( 
    <DialogInput 
        isDialogVisible={props.visible}
        title={props.title}
        message={props.messsage}
        submitInput={ (inputText) => props.saveInput(inputText, props.title)}
        closeDialog={() => props.closeDialog()}
        textInputProps={{keyboardType:'numeric'}}
    />
 );}
```